# FOS Elastica, Search in whole sentences

Tags: elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I am pretty new to elasticsearch and FOSElastica,
I would like to get relevant result of maped field, which represent name of the school.

my config:

```
fos_elastica:
clients:
    default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
indexes:
    app:
        settings:
                index:
                  analysis:
                    analyzer:
                      czech :
                        tokenizer:    standard
                        filter   :    [czech_stop, czech_stemmer ,lowercase, asciifolding]
                    filter:
                      czech_stop:
                        type:   stop
                        stopwords:  _czech_
                      czech_stemmer:
                        type:   stemmer
                        languague:  czech

        types:
            school:
                mappings:
                    name:
                        type: string
                        analyzer : czech
                        boost : 10
                persistence:
                    driver: orm
                    model:  Yearbook\SUBundle\Entity\School
                    provider: ~
                    listener:
                       immediate: ~
                    finder: ~
```

In name field is stored name of school. I get zero results using command line `fos:elastica:search school "Hi"`, however searching for whole word works fine `fos:elastica:search school "High"`

I also triend different ways to get results in controller, but none of it worked. I think the problem may be in config file.

I did not find any related problem.
Thank you guys for your replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found solution,**

by adding custom_filter EdgeNGram to **confing** file:

```
fos_elastica:
clients:
    default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
indexes:
    app:
        settings:
                index:
                  analysis:
                    analyzer:
                      custom_search_analyzer :
                        type     :    custom
                        tokenizer:    standard
                        filter   :    [czech_stop, czech_stemmer ,lowercase, asciifolding,standard]
                      custom_index_analyzer :
                        tokenizer:    standard
                        type     :    custom
                        filter   :    [czech_stop, czech_stemmer ,lowercase, asciifolding,standard,custom_filter]
                    filter:
                      custom_filter:
                          type: edgeNGram
                          side: front
                          min_gram: 1
                          max_gram: 20
                      czech_stop:
                        type:   stop
                        stopwords:  _czech_
                      czech_stemmer:
                        type:   stemmer
                        languague:  czech

        types:
            school:
                mappings:
                    name:
                        type: string
                        search_analyzer : custom_search_analyzer
                        index_analyzer : custom_index_analyzer
                        boost : 10
                    urlFriendly:
                        type: string
                persistence:
                    driver: orm
                    model:  Yearbook\SUBundle\Entity\School
                    provider: ~
                    listener:
                       immediate: ~
                    finder: ~
```

getting list of results in controller:

```
            $needle=$request->request->get('needle');

        $index =$this->container->get('fos_elastica.index.app.school');

        $searchQuery=new QueryString();
        $searchQuery->setParam('query',$needle);
        $searchQuery->setDefaultOperator('OR');
        $searchQuery->setParam('fields',array('name','urlFriendly'));
        $results=$index->search($searchQuery,10)->getResults();
```